# how to use cakephp and conditon for sql

Tags: php, cakephp

```
    $this->Paginator->settings=array(
        'conditions' => 
            array(
            'Event.status'=>'success',
            'Event.type'=>'estate',
            ),
        'limit'=>12,
        'order' => 'Event.created DESC'
    );
```

problem is that i want to use 
`'Event.type'=>'home'`, also in condition like that

```
           array(
            'Event.status'=>'success',
            'Event.type'=>'estate',
            'Event.type'=>'home'
            ),
```

how i can use it one field condition on two different data in cakephp

Answer (score 1):

```
$types=array('home','estate');     
$this->Paginator->settings=array(
            'conditions' => 
                array(
                'Event.status'=>'success',
                'Event.type'=>$types

                ),
            'limit'=>12,
            'order' => 'Event.created DESC'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a `OR` condition -

```
       array(
        'Event.status'=>'success',
        'OR' => array(
                 'estate', 'home',
                ),
        ),
```